# Polars, multiply columns

Tags: python, python-polars

This should be a straightforward python question, but it's not working for me. I have a list of strings, the columns, as well as an integer, with repeated number of columns as the output.

```
multi_cols = lpd.columns
len(multi_cols)
103
multi_cols = [[k]*6 for k in lpd.columns]
len(multi_cols)
103
```

Why does this output 103?

Answer (score 1):

The resulting `multi_cols` is a *list of lists* of length 103, with each element being a list of length 6.

There are several ways to do what you are looking for, I'd refer to this question: [How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

The length of `multi_cols` is `103` because it is a list containing 103 items.
The instruction `[k]*6` results in a list of 6 items.
And thus `multi_cols` is a list of lists.